# [] operator not supported for strings in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have code in WordPress
I have the error  PHP Fatal error:  [] operator not supported for strings in

```
$file1 = '';
 while (false !== ($file1 = readdir($dir2))) {
  if($file1 != "." && $file1 != "..") {
     $files[$item][] = $file1;
    }
 }
```

I am using php 5.4 version. Any ideas?

Comment: `$files[$item]` is a string, not an array. https://3v4l.org/GXuXg

Answer (score 0):

[`readdir()`](http://php.net/readdir) accepts a **file handle**, not a string:

Quoting from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php):

> **dir_handle**:
>   The directory handle resource previously opened with `opendir()`. If the directory handle is not specified, the last link opened by `opendir()` is assumed.`

So perhaps use [`opendir()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) first?